# How to use multiprocessing library for this problem? I also would like to know is it feasible or not for my problem

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have an image whose size is (1107060 x 1054300). I am trying to split this image into tiles as by dividing it by 512.

```
nx = width/512 = 2163
ny = height/512 = 2060

M = []

for y in range(ny):
    for x in range(nx):
        .....................
        .....................
        .....................
        M.append(..)
```

As you can see above, the number of tiles is very high and it takes approximately 22 minutes to finish each y instances. For example, when y = 0, x run from (0-2163) and it takes 22 minutes to run this single instance. Likewise, to run all instances for y (from 0 to 2060) it might take more than 25 days. I guess.

So to reduce the execution time, I want to use multiprocessing or parallel processor.

And, later I want to save the output as serially as in a list.
In, my Laptop there are 12 cores and 16 GB Ram.
I don't know how to use the multiprocessing library for my problem.

Any suggestion will be very helpful.
Thank you

Comment: that's a **very** big image; presumably in a very exotic file format.  I find it unlikely that anybody can make many useful suggestions based on the details you've provided.  do you really have a multiple terabyte file?  if so then you'll need to get guidance from the file format as to how to efficiently access the data, otherwise, many more details would be appreciated!

Comment: It's a .ome.tif, WSI file and its size are around 247GB. I can preprocess it but it's slow and takes lots of days. I want to get output fast.
I think utilizing multiprocessing might help some what to solve it with in a day or two days.

Comment: Is the processing of each tile independent from the others?

Comment: @Yuvi and what are you doing with those tiles?  just appending them into a list will quickly cause your computer to run out of free memory and start swapping (and hence run approx a thousand times or more slower).  I've not used those files before, but it sounds like they just use TIFF as a container for multi-resolution JPEG encoded tiles.  hence decoding the file will cause it to drastically increase in size (e.g. 10 times the size)

Comment: I'd suggest taking a step back and considering what processing you want to do as the tiles are decoded.  separating the loading from processing is likely too inefficient

Comment: @SamMason Thank you for your comment, I am reading each tile and later I am appending their bytes one by one in M list. And, later I will convert them in Dicom. I am trying to save each tiles bytes buffer in the M list serially. I hope now you have understood it.
please check the above question.

M = []
    for y in range(nYTiles):
        for x in range(nXTiles):
            bf_tiles = Image.open()     
            instance_byte_buffer = BytesIO()
            bf_tiles.save(instance_byte_buffer, "JPEG")
            t_org = instance_byte_buffer.getvalue()
            M.append(t_org)

Comment: @ffdoctor Yes processing of each tile is independent of others.